# P4 Plugin in Jenkins doesn't automatically trigger check-in build

Tags: jenkins, perforce

I am using Jenkins to auto build Maven projects triggered by each check-in from Perforce. But why doesn't it trigger? It can't detect the checkin.

Please see my attached settings in P4 Plugin in Jenkins.

[image]

Comment: Your build triggers appear to be correct. Can you show a screenshot of the entire Source Code Management section (the section above what you are showing now)?

Comment: @JacobRitchie, this actually, but it re-build every 2 minutes, which isn't what I want. I only want it build once whenever something is checked in.

Answer (score 1):

The 'Poll SCM' will periodically look for new changes submitted within the scope of your workspace view.  If changes are submitted elsewhere (i.e. not in your workspace view) then no build will take place.

The 'Perforce triggered build' is BETA and will require a P4D Server 'change-commit' trigger (an external script) to fire the build.  Change details [here](https://swarm.workshop.perforce.com/changes/15403).

If the 'Perforce triggered build' is selected it subscribes the Jenkins Job to a list which, during an external trigger event, is evaluated to see if there are any new changes.

I only intended for one option to be used. If the 'Perforce triggered build' is selected then the 'Poll SCM' will be redundant; at best the event would have already occurred, at worst it could trigger a build of the same change.

If you are trying to trigger other Jobs as the result of a change then you will need to use a 'Post Build Action' like 'Build other projects' or look for a custom 'Plugin' to do something similar.

Comment: I don't know what "Perforce triggered build" means. So I should get rid of it. Still, I can't get it working properly.